# How do you add the number of observations for each category when summarising using gtsummary for a continuous variable over two categorical variables?

Tags: nested, categories, summarize, continuous, gtsummary

In example below,

```
  # keep the continuous var and the two categorical variables
  select(trt, age, grade) %>%
  group_nest(grade) %>%
  mutate(
    tbl = map2(
      grade, data, 
      ~tbl_summary(.y, by = trt, 
                   label = list(age = paste("Age: Grade", .x)), missing = "no")
    )
  ) %>% 
  pull(tbl) %>% 
  tbl_stack() %>%
  as_tibble()
```

Where should the number of observation per age: grade be added?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the option

`statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{N_nonmiss}")`

solved my problem. Thanks